# How to show the printable document directly in acrobat with out saving?

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdf-generation, acrobat

I am using PD4ML to print a PDF file and It is working fine. Now the thing is I want show that file directly in acrobat with out save that file. In Local version I am using

```
Program.launch(getFilePath());
```

It is working fine but in web version I am unable to get that.
Can you please suggest me, Its very helpful.

Thanks,
Vara Kumar PJD

Comment: By the way, you've been here for 5 months and you haven't accepted a single answer to your questions. Why?

Comment: I don't know how to accept answers. I am just seeing the answers thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web isn't like your desktop, so forget about doing things on the web the way you do them on the desktop without at least some effort.

Know that you don't read PDF files on the web using Acrobat without a browser plugin. Or some other reader like [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/).

My recommendation: forget about doing it this way. Either server your pdf as a file that can be downloaded, or read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html) about embedding PDF in HTML.

Comment: thanks, One more thing is I don't want show that file within browser. I want show that seperatly

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will be possible: "showing file outside browser in an application without user consent" because that is how browser are made for security reason. The best you can do is, as pointed in earlier post is by darioo, to show file in browser or prompt user to download/open.